# reaching the fourth column value from results list

Tags: c#

I have this method that returns a `Setting`type and i wanted to check the value of the fourth column -

current code:

```
public Setting TestSettings(Example _example, String type)
{
    var results = _example.GetExample("Testing");
    return results;
}
```

Setting Model

```
string Description { get; set; }
Guid? Guid1 { get; set; }
Guid? Guid2 { get; set; }
string Key { get; set; }
string Value { get; set; }
```

GetExample

```
public Setting GetExample(string key)
        {
            using (var db = MyDataContext.StoredProcs)
            {
                return db.GetExample<Setting>(key, _curGuid1, _curGuid2, SettingExtensions.SettingFactory());
            }
        }
```

I want to access the (Key) in the Setting results to verify it is equal to type.

Comment: Do you have a class definition for the `Settings` class? How do you access these items from an instance of the Settings class when you use it after it's returned?

Comment: @Sean yes i have a model class for `Setting` and i am returning a list of results i need - i am just getting a hold on the fourth column. The results are based on a call made to the stored procedure

Comment: Could you post the code for the `Setting` class please?

Comment: Could you post the code for the `Settings` class and the `Example.GetExample` method?

Comment: @Sean i went ahead and posted - i am interesting in getting a handle on the Key value

Comment: Surely you already know the key? It's being passed in to the `GetExample` function isn't it? Anyway it would be as simple as simple property access: `if (results.Key == type) { /* code here */ }`

Comment: @Sean yes i do - thanks i will give that a go - you should add it as an answer so you can take credit for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know the key, it's being passed in to the `GetExample` function:

```
var results = _example.GetExample("Testing"); // <--- here
```

Otherwise it should be as simple as getting the property from the result:

```
public Setting TestSettings(Example _example, String type)
{
    var results = _example.GetExample("Testing");

    if (results.Key == type)
    {
        // whatever you need to do here
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: what if i wanted to write the returned results to JSON?

Comment: I believe you would use the `JavaScriptSerializer` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx